# Surface area of a solid

Tags: surface-integrals

So I need to find the surface area of this solid defined as: $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ where $z\geq \frac{1}{2}$

I tried to do the following:

$x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}$ into $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$

$Fx(x,y)= -\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}$ by using u-substitution to make $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}(-2x)$

$Fy(x,y)= -\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}$ by using u-substitution to make $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}(-2y)$

Surface area formula for a sphere: $S=\int\int\sqrt{(Fx)^2+(Fy)^2+1}dA$

$S=\int\int\sqrt{(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}})^2+(\frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}})^2} = \int\int\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{1-x^2-y^2}+\frac{y^2}{1-x^2-y^2}+1} dA$

$\int\int\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-x^2-y^2}}dA$ from my book formula: $\int\int\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2-x^2-y^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2-x^2-y^2}+1}dA$ = $\int\int\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{a^2-x^2-y^2}}dA$

=$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}dA = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}rdrd\theta = \int\int(1-r^2)^\frac{-1}{2}rdrd\theta$ <--using $r^2=x^2+y^2$ as a polar coordinate

From this point onward I just need to figure out the integral boundaries and evaluate, but I want to make sure I got to this step correctly first. I'm not even sure I used the right formula, so I'd like some feedback on if this is the right approach or I messed something up along the way

Comment: Do you know how to calculate area using surface parametrizations? If so, either cylindrical or spherical coordinates yields an easier calculation overall. (That said, give how far you've gotten, you can integrate $r$ easily via the substitution $u - 1 - r^{2}$.)

Comment: Have a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap

Answer (score 1):

The solid is the upper half of the sphere with radius 1. I assume you want to add the bottom of it too. So, that gives $2\pi+\pi=3\pi$. The $4\pi$ comes from the radial part of the surface integral wich you half. Do you want to calculate it explicitly?

**EDIT**: As Raffaele pointed out, I was wrong with the answer because the solid is only a quarter of its height not half. The correct answer is the surface equals $\pi+\frac{3}{4}\pi$. Where the first term is the surface of the spherical cap and the second term is the surface of the base circle.

To show this, here we shall use spherical coordinates. I choose 
$$x=r\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\y=r\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\z=r\cos\theta.$$
We will use the spherical surface element in this coordinates and integrate the part of the sphere we need. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131735/surface-element-in-spherical-coordinates) is a derivation of the surface element. It also includes a sketch of what $r,\theta,\varphi$ represent.

The surface element is $r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\varphi$. For us $r=1$ and $\varphi\in [0,2\pi)$. The angle $\theta$ determines how much of the sphere we integrate from top to bottom. We want only $\frac{1}{4}$. If we choose $\theta\in[0,\pi)$ and integrate over the surface we will get the surface of a sphere. We have to restrict $\theta$ to $[0,\pi-\alpha)$.  We need to find what $\alpha$ is. I have made a sketch where the angle is $\alpha$.
[image]

In this picture $b=\frac{1}{2}$, i.e. the minimal $z$ value. This implies that $a=\sqrt{3}/2$. We can solve for the left angle in the triangle, lets call it $\alpha'=\arcsin(1/2)$. To get $\alpha$ we must the $\pi/2$ below to it. So, $$\alpha=\alpha'+\pi/2=\pi/3.$$
Finally this means $\theta\in(0,\pi/3]$. Let's integrate
$$
S=\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/3}\int_{\varphi=0}^{2\pi}\sin\theta d\varphi d\theta=\pi.
$$
The base is $$S'=a^2\pi=\frac{3}{4}\pi.$$

Comment: To both commenter, I'm not really sure exactly. I was just given the problem and I tried to solve it using methods in the book. The formula used the explicit form of z=sqrt(a^2-x^2-y^2) for somewhat similar problems. So, I tried solving that way. I am relatively new to all of this. Usually they give some other boundaries along with the problem like 'above the xy plane' or 'enclosed by the surface' but this is just z>≠1/2

Comment: What do you mean by z>≠1/2 ? Do you mean $z>1/2$ or $z\geq 1/2$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. My phone added that. Z is greater than or equal to 1/2

Comment: Ok, to call it a solid, I would say you should consider the bottom part too. Your integrals do not. Luckily integration is linear. Just calculate the sufrace of the sphere and add the surface of the circle at the base

Comment: @ty the upper half would be if $z\ge 0$ this is another thing I think you call in English "Spherical cap". the surface is $S=2\pi rh$ where h is the distance between the centre of the base circle and the "north pole". In this case $S=\pi$

If you want to add the base circle you must add $S'=\pi (2 h r-h^2)=\dfrac{3}{4}\pi$