# Why I cannot get the surface area of sphere by using this consideration

Tags: integration

I'm dividing the surface area to many small area that represent by formula $dA=2*\pi*y*dx$ but I cannot get the surface area which is $4\pi r^2$.

Can anyone point out where my mistake is ?

I would get $\pi^2 r^2$ as compare to $4\pi r^2$ , surface area is smaller than $4\pi r^2$ since value of pi is 3.142...

[image: POLAR CIRCLE]

Comment: Your formula for $dA$ is incorrect, because the surface is curved. You should take this onto account, which leads to an extra multiplicative factor $\sqrt{1 +y'^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the Perimeter of Circle $2 \pi y$ , you are multiplying by $dx$ , which is Parallel to $X$-Axis.
Likewise , you might multiply by $dy$ which is Parallel to $Y$-Axis.

Naturally , these 2 are wrong & will wrongly give the $\pi ^2$ :
**We have to multiply by the Curve length $dS$ along the Circle.**

$dS = \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$

Plug that in & then Check that you get Correct Surface Area.

$dA = (2 \pi y) dS$

**Image Visualization :**

[image: dS]

(1) Perimeter of Circle with Center on $X$-Axis is $2 \pi y$ , when we multiply that by $dx$ , Area is not along that Circle Curve.

(2) Alternately , Perimeter of Circle with Center on $Y$-Axis is $2 \pi x$ , when we multiply by $dy$ , Area is not along that Circle Curve.

(3) Correct way is to consider the Circle Curve , which has length $dS = \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2} = [\sqrt{1+(dy/dx)^2}]dx$ :
Then Area $dA = 2 \pi y dS$
Integrating this $dA$ with the limits will give the Necessary Surface Area.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong formula for the area element. Assuming you're evaluating this area using a surface of revolution, you should have
$$ dA = 2 \pi y(x) \sqrt{1 + \left(y'(x)\right)^2} \,dx$$
where $y(x) = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$. Then, the desired surface area is
$$ SA = \int_{-r}^r 2 \pi y(x) \sqrt{1 + \left(y'(x)\right)^2} \,dx = 4\pi r^2$$
Basically, you're missing the factor of "$\sqrt{1 + \left(y'(x)\right)^2}$" that accounts for the curvature of the surface (and which doesn't appear when you're doing **volumes** of revolution). If you're curious about why this factor is there, [check this link out](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/UCD_Mat_21B%3A_Integral_Calculus/6%3A_Applications_of_Definite_Integrals/6.4%3A_Areas_of_Surfaces_of_Revolution).

You can simplify the above integral by using polar coordinates, which I see you tried to do in your work. That is, we have
$$\begin{align}
x &= r\cos(\theta)\\
y &= r\sin(\theta)
\end{align}$$
where $r$ is fixed. Note that
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/d\theta}{dx/d\theta} = \frac{r\cos\theta}{-r\sin\theta} = -\cot\theta$$
Then,
$$\begin{align}
SA &= \int_{-r}^r 2 \pi y(x) \sqrt{1 + \left(y'(x)\right)^2} \,dx\\
&= -2\pi r^2 \int_{\pi}^0 \sin^2(\theta) \sqrt{1 + \cot^2(\theta)} \,d\theta\\
&= 2\pi r^2 \int_0^\pi \sin\theta \,d\theta\\
&= 4\pi r^2
\end{align}$$
as desired.

In the realm of multivariable calculus, one would perform this integral using [spherical coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131735/surface-element-in-spherical-coordinates). Here, the the area element would be
$$ dA = r^2 \sin\theta \,d\theta d\varphi$$
where $\theta$ is now the polar angle, and $\varphi$ is the azimuthal angle. The the surface area is then simply given by
$$ SA = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} r^2 \sin\theta \,d\theta d\varphi = 4\pi r^2 $$