# From where does this differential come from?

Tags: integration, derivatives, surface-integrals, line-integrals

In one my physics classes I was finding the charge of a half sphere with constant radius $R$ (and I got this expression (just for context purposes):
$$Q=\int_S \rho dS$$ and now my teacher did this $dS=2\pi rRd\theta=2\pi rR^2\sin\theta d\theta$. How did he got that differential?

---

**Second question**. Why is there only one differential $d\theta$ in this case for a surface, shouldn't there be 2 at least? Like I thought for curves or lines it was one differential and surfaces 2 differentials and volumen 3 differentials?

Comment: The elementary region $dS$ of a given curved space should be $dS=R^2\sin \theta \mathrm d\theta \mathrm d\varphi$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37044/explain-iint-mathrm-dx-mathrm-dy-iint-r-mathrm-d-alpha-mathrm-dr?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the differential in polar coordinates, and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131735/surface-element-in-spherical-coordinates) for the differential in spherical coordinates.